# How to create mutlipul Orders of different things

Tags: mysql, orders

i am creating a code for a Uni Case study for a DVD Shop and i was using the bellow code for my customer Order database but i realized it would only let me order one DVD at a time. ideally i need it so you can have more than one DVD id per order how would i go about doing that. For example i have the following question 
"d.List the customer names whose purchase is more than £50"

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_ORDER
(
ORDER_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
CUSTOMER_ID INT NOT NULL,
DVD_ID INT NOT NULL,
DVD_QUANTITY varchar(3) NOT NULL,
ORDER_DATE date NOT NULL,
ORDER_COST varchar(6) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (DVD_ID) references DVD (DVD_ID),
PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dbrisk, the way I'm most-familiar seeing this done would be having a table for "orders" (the complete order consisting of one or more items) and "order_items" (an individual line or item contained in an order). The "orders" table will contain all information or references to information about the order excluding the individual products in the order. Then, order_items will include a field like "order_id" to reference more than one item back to the order bucket.

I've created an example of what I'm describing below. These tables are made up of orders #1 and #2. Order #1 consists of 1 unit of product_id 111 and 2 units of product_id 222. Order #2 consists of a single unit of product 333.

```
ORDERS
id      acct_id     created_date
1       123         04-30-2014
2       456         04-30-2014

ORDER_ITEMS
id      order_id        product_id      quantity
1       1               111             1
2       1               222             2
3       2               333             1
```

To query for a complete order, join order_items to order using order.id and order_item.order_id.